# Solving Huffman Code Tree

Tags: math, huffman-code

I was expecting a little help in my discrete maths problem. Is there any way to shorten up the binary tree or I have to construct for the whole data below.

> 27. Construct a Huffman code for the letters of the English alphabet
>       where the frequencies of letters in typical English
>       text are as shown in this table.
>
> [image: Here is The data table]

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a true Huffman code and to satisfy the requirements of the exercise you  do need a binary tree. There are alternative ways of doing it some discussed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding.

You could put all the low frequency letters in the same  bin and just use a simple scheme for the 8 lowest frequency letters. So B=000, J=001, K=010, P=011, Q=100, V=101, X=110, Z=111. Just append these codes to the Huffman coding with BJKPQVXZ treated as a single character.